# Как организовать двойное тернарное условие

Tags: c#

Есть две переменные, значение которых может быть либо пустым, либо значение типа "город"

```
var blago = sum5 + sum6>0?"Благовещенск":"";
var moskva = sum7 + sum8 + sum9>0?"Москва":"";
```

Я хочу объединить обе строки в одну, однако может быть что одна из переменных будет пустой и тогда может получиться `Благовещенск,`, а должно получиться `Благовещенск` без запятой.

```
var rezCity = blago+","+moskva;
```

Comment: У вас запятая не там стоит, вам надо запятую в условие

Comment: Я не знаю какие у вас входные данные, поэтому напишу так:  `var rezCity =blago + ( ((blago.ToString()=="") || (moskva.ToString()==""))?"":","  )+moskva;` Если blago априори заполнено - условие можно упростить.

Comment: Либо так `var rezCity =blago + ( ((sum6>0) && (sum9>0))?",":"" )+moskva;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проще всего такое делается через списки строк:

```
var cities = new List<string>();

if (sum5 + sum6 > 0)
  cities.Add("Благовещенск");

if (sum7 + sum8 + sum9)
  cities.Add("Москва");

var rezCity = string.Join(",", cities);
```

Если же переменные `blago` и `moskva` обязательны для использования - надо проверять их. И учить логику: очевидно же, запятая должна ставиться когда обе переменные заполнены:

```
var rezCity = blago + (blago != "" && moskva != "" ? "," : "") + moskva;
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать следующее. Оставьте `blago` и `moskva` как есть:

```
var blago = sum5 + sum6>0?"Благовещенск":"";
var moskva = sum7 + sum8 + sum9>0?"Москва":"";
```

Напишите вспомогательную функцию для объединения строк в одну через разделитель (за исключением пустых), например:

```
string Join(string separator, params string[] s)
{
    return String.Join(separator, s.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
}
```

Ее вызов даст нужный результат:

```
// Join(",", "Благовещенск", "Москва") вернет Благовещенск,Москва
// Join(",", "", "Москва") вернет Москва
// Join(",", "Благовещенск", "")  вернет Благовещенск

var resCity = Join(",", blago, moskva);
```

Comment: Вам мама не говорила, что нехорошо передавать в linq-методы функции с побочными эффектами? Чем вам обычный цикл foreach не угодил? Вызов Aggregate же нечитаем...

Comment: А чем стоковый `string.Join` отличается?

Comment: @VladD тут метод с фильтрацией пустых строк же. Стоковый ничего не фильтрует.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А, точно. Тогда я бы не делал велосипед, а отфильтровал пустые строки (например, используя `Where`).

Comment: ну и вместо новой функции можно было просто массив/список создать: `new [] {blago, moskva}`